# Capabilities of Instagram API - is there a method for reading your dm's

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is there any possibility using official Instagram API for **getting dm's** of my account and also **sending dm's** to user's account?

If there are none, how dangerous it's for small account to use private API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not the official API for Instagram Direct.
Using unofficial private API violates terms of use, so you can use it at your own risk.